Why does the texture do this after the knife tool is used to cut out the jog wheel?
Trying to make this cdj in Blender but whenever I cut the jog wheel out the texture goes completely faded. I've tried unwrapping it in all sorts of ways and I even tried a new file where I cut the jog wheel out first but still the same problem.
Even even the texture is deleted the fading remains. I've attached as much info as I can (also no modifiers or anything I've only used the shading tab and UV editing tab)



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
